# ESP8266 - if sdk_wifi_station_scan() cannot sdk_wifi_station_set_config()

Tags: android, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to work with ESP-Open-SDK and ESP-OPEN-RTOS. I use the ESP8266 LoLin NodeMcu V3.

If I call the functions

```
sdk_wifi_set_opmode( NULL_MODE );
sdk_wifi_set_opmode( STATION_MODE );
sdk_wifi_station_scan( NULL, function_cb )
```

I've got the list of all WiFi available. Every thing is fine

Then, if I call the functions

```
sdk_wifi_set_opmode( NULL_MODE );
sdk_wifi_set_opmode( STATION_MODE );
sdk_wifi_station_scan( NULL, ... )
sdk_wifi_station_set_config(&config);
```

I get the list of all WiFi available but I cannot connect to the WiFi and the sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status() returns always 0

If I call

```
sdk_wifi_set_opmode( STATION_MODE );
sdk_wifi_station_scan( NULL, ... )
sdk_wifi_station_set_config(&config);
```

I get a connection to the WiFi and sdk_wifi_station_get_connect_status returns STATION_GOT_IP and I receive the IP, GateWay and networks values but the connection is done during the scanning of WiFi and I don't any control on the WiFI I want to connect to.

If I do the same thing with Arduino ScanNetwork Example, sometimes, I receive garbage like

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
vac02aff5
~ld
```

That application worked before correctly.

Do I have to erase memory, is there any configuration to change in the module (ESP8266). To I have to connect any PIN to any volage to get something running and stable.

Last week, I had a small program written with Arduino, which was scanning the WiFi, connecting to the right WiFi, sending/receiving UDP packet and handling TCP/Internet (port 80) as client/server. Every thing was fine and suddently, problems appeared.

I am wondering if that module (Esp8266-LoLin-NodeMcu) and developing tools are stables enough to build industrial application around it.

Comment: If we execute esptool.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 --baud 460800 erase_flash
and then flash the memory with a program to connect to a WiFi, we cannot get an IP. If we run it again, the program get an IP very quickly. Very strange

Comment: In the file app_main.c, user_init() is called by sdk_user_init_task(), called by user_start_phase2(), called by sdk_user_start(), called by the loader from the interrupt vector. The information from the last execution is loaded. See below

After the user_init() call, the data from the connection is save in memory and reload when any program is execute again. 

So, if the last execution was for a mode STATION, the next execution will for a Station.

Comment: I would guess you should connect to AP only after the scan finishes and calls the "scan done" callback.